# Using SVNBridge with TFS (not CodePlex)

Tags: tfs, svnbridge

I'm trying to access my TFS Server using SVNBridge so I can work disconnected.  I tried using the server-based as well as client-based solution.  I'm just getting internal server 500 errors returned.  I'm not sure I'm connecting to the site correctly though.

Other posts I've read concerning SVNBridge seem to exclusively be about CodePlex and connecting to it through a CodePlex specific URL.

I'm trying to connect to my own TFS server and wondering how to properly format the URL.  Do I need to do something special for that?  I feel like I've tried everything.  Anybody have any success doing such a thing?

So apprently the problem is related to TFS 2010 Beta 2.  The issue is being tracked here:

http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=77164

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer but I just spent the better part of my weekend getting it to work, mostly through trial and error so here is what I learned.

You **CANNOT** download the zip files and get anything to work if you are using TFS-2010. Instead you **MUST** download the source code and compile the thing for yourself.

You have to do the build on a computer with IIS installed to use the website project as is. This is what I did rather than change the project to use the development web server.

If you don't have VS-2008 installed anymore you can just upgrade the whole solution to VS-2010 and everything will be fine. I even changed the target of the website project to the 4.0 Framework with minimal issues. I had to unload the TestsRequiredTfsClient project and the Tools.HttpSend project to get the rest of the projects to build.

After you have built the project you need to follow a couple of steps that are outlined on the [SvnBidge home page](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) in order to get the bits into the right location on the web server. Once that is complete then you need to tune up the web.config file.

Here are the appSettings that you need to change and the values you need to use:

```
<add key="LogPath" value="--directoryYouWantToKeepLogsIn--" />
<add key="DomainIncludesProjectName" value="False" />
<add key="TfsUrl" value="http://--tfsServerName--:8080/tfs/--projectCollection--" />
<add key="ReadAllUserDomain" value="--yourDomain--" />
<add key="ReadAllUserName" value="--domainUserName--" />
<add key="ReadAllUserPassword" value="--domainUserNamePassword--" />
```

If you decided to upgrade the website to the 4.0 Framework don't forget that you need to update the application pool to because it was probably created as 2.0.

After you are almost done now that the website is set up. You still need to install some performance counters from the SvnBridge.PerfCounter.Installer project. After complication just copy those bits over to the same server you just installed the website on and run the exe.

**THIS DIDN'T WORK**

*Okay so last but not least is security. I don't use the Digest security because all of my users have a windows login so I left anonymous access enabled and then disabled all other forms of access except Windows Authentication.*

Windows Authentication didn't work for all of the users, some of them were remote. After looking at the source code it became clear that Basic Authentication was the only choice that was going to work. I needed the users to log in as them selves and then have that username passed into TFS so that as the check-ins are done they can be recorded to the correct user.

RP

Comment: Thank you, Ryan!  These instructions work great!  I also had to remove the WebDAVModule in IIS Virtual Directory > Modules because I was getting "405: Method Not Allowed" errors in the TortoiseSVN client and NetBeans IDE.